If a mount provokes opportunity attacks, can its rider be targeted?
Re: Mounted Combat, the 2014 PHB states:

if the mount provokes an opportunity attack while you’re on it, the attacker can target you or the mount.

However, the 2024 PHB makes no such caveat in the Mounted Combat rules. Likewise, there is no explicit mention of it in the Opportunity Attacks rules. Though, the OA rules state:

You can make an Opportunity Attack when a creature that you can see leaves your reach. To make the attack, take a Reaction to make one melee attack ... against that creature...

They also stipulate:

You ... don’t provoke an Opportunity Attack ... when you are moved without using your movement, action, Bonus Action, or Reaction.

So, mounted movement seems to qualify as an exception to provoking OAs.
Has the 2014 rule been intentionally removed? Is it clarified elsewhere?

The question in your title and body are notably different. Are you asking IF that is the case or are you asking WHY that is the case?

Principally, I'm asking if it is the case--i.e. is it clarified elsewhere? Secondarily, assuming the rule has been removed, I'm asking if it was removed by intention or omission--e.g. Did they determine that it was a bad rule or did the editors fail to include it? It seems to me to be a valuable part of mounted combat. Otherwise, a controlled mount should almost always take the Dodge action, unless the opportunity attacker has a high probability of hitting the mount even with disadvantage, and it is is much less risky to ride an independent mount through combat.

RAW, no.
The rules are clear that if "you are moved without using your movement," you don't provoke an opportunity attack. Other than when you mount or dismount, the mount's movement—not yours—is used while you are riding it.
Since the rule that states "the attacker can target you or the mount" is no longer present, one must conclude that only the mount provokes an opportunity attack when it moves out of its enemy's reach.
Since the mount may use its action to Disengage, this should not be too much of a problem. And if your mount Disengages, there is no longer a question of whether you as the rider can be targeted with the opportunity attack—you cannot.

Has the 2014 rule been intentionally removed?

I know of no designer commentary that answers that question one way or the other.

Is it clarified elsewhere?

Not that I could find. The 2024 Dungeon Master's Guide may contain further guidance about when a monster can or should take an opportunity attack. We won't know until it is released.
